# Inequality in geodesic quadrupel

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact complete Riemannian manifold. Consider the geodesic quadrupel $ABCD$ where $l:=d(A,B)=d(B,C)=d(C,D)=d(A,D) \geq \frac{1}{2}$ and $d(B,D),d(A,C) \geq 1$. Let $x \in CD$ and $y \in AB$. Is it true that then $d(x,y)\geq \frac{1}{4}$ ? I have tried a lot of things but non of them worked, mostly I tried to do it by the triangle inequaity. I even do not know if its true.

Greetings
Lena